# Why I get additional symbols when read the fie in Java

Tags: java, file, readfile

When I read txt file and print it on console I get at the beginning two more symbols ��
Does anyone know why.. Here is the code...

```
try{
            File file=new File("...\\test.txt");    //creates a new file instance  
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);   //reads the file  
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);  //creates a buffering character input stream  
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();    //constructs a string buffer with no characters  
            String line;  
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)  
            {  
            sb.append(line);      //appends line to string buffer  
            sb.append("\n");     //line feed   
            }  
            fr.close();    //closes the stream and release the resources  
            System.out.println("Contents of File: ");  
            System.out.println(sb.toString());   //returns a string that textually represents the object  
        }  
        catch(Exception e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

Comment: We don't know how you created the file in the first place. I *suspect* this is a byte-order mark, but we can't really tell without more information.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a BOM, but those only occur in UTF-8 files (or UTF-16), and the code is not trying to read a UTF-8 encoded file, which means you expected the file to be in e.g. ISO-8859-1 (or Windows-1252). Open the file in whatever text editor was used to create it, then re-save the file in ISO-8859-1.